# unable to review a low quality post due to an audit message

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts

Today I was reviewing a low quality post. I was trying to post a comment on it but it is giving me error:

> This is an audit

[image]

Usually it never happened to me this way. Whether an item is mock audit or not is told only after you have reviewed the item. Also, end in the end I couldn't make the comment and I had to skip the review item after making several attempts to make a comment.

Why is it happening? Is it a bug or is it an audit? What is supposed to be done when we face it?

Answer (score 3):

> Why is it happening?

The post is an audit.

> Is it a bug or is it an audit?

It's an audit.

> What is supposed to be done when we face it?

You don't need to do anything to the post.  Audits are posts that don't actually need any attention.  Known good audits are good posts, and known-bad audits will have already been deleted.  You can go to the post directly if you want to take an action outside of the review queue, but from the queue's perspective, *there is nothing to do*.

Comment: actually for the first time, I faced such an audit message during the review itself. Normally I expect that it gives me a pass/failed audit message after I've finished the review. e.g. in this case the system might have given me an audit failed warning if I would have pressed the `Looks OK` button directly even though it is a code-only answer without sufficient description. So it was kind of news to me. I'm wondering if it will show me the same audit pop-up if I would have pressed `Recommend Deletion` button or would have taken me to a fresh page to show me the result of audit success/failure?

Comment: @RBT That particular message is only shown when you try to comment on a post that's an audit.